# Executing method on object kotlin

Tags: java, functional-programming, kotlin

I'm rather new to Kotlin and am still trying to get to grips with it.
Let's say I have this interface:

```
interface A{
    fun add()
}
```

I have a function and something that implements this interface:

```
val calc = /*Something that implements interface A*/
fun op(func:()->Unit){
       //Some code
}
```

Finally, in my main function, I have this:

```
fun main(args:Array<String>){
    op(A::add)
}
```

Is there a way for function `op` to run the given function using the val `calc`? (Assuming that the given function exists)

Comment: Change `op(A::add)` to `op(calc::add)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd like to write something like this:

```
interface A{
    fun add()
}

class AImpl: A {
    override fun add() {
        println("Hello, Aimpl")
    }
}

val calc = AImpl()
fun op(func: A.()->Unit){
    calc.func()   
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    op(A::add)
}
```

This is called *Function Literal with Receiver* in Kotlin. The relevant documentation is here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver

In this case you provide a Lambda function as a parameter that can be called on any `A` objects. And in the function `op` I call this method on ther `calc` object.